# GitHub SystemJS README.md table of contents

Tags: github, systemjs, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I've been writing some README markdown lately, and I wanted to know how the heck some open source projects `README.md` files render with an automatic table of contents?  If you look at `SystemJS` for example, their `README.md` file loads with a TOC however their markdown source doesn't include that table of contents.

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

It has to come from somewhere... See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a table of contents on the page you linked to. Could you please upload a screenshot?

Comment: Sure thing, try refreshing your page or something?  All I know is that it renders there for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't see the table of contents in your screenshot. It looks like you might have installed [this Github Toc Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-toc/nalkpgbfaadkpckoadhlkihofnbhfhek)?

> Allows to show you a "table of content" generated by Github project README or WIKI.

The formatting of the two screenshots is very similar, including the somewhat unusual treatment of nested lists with blue dashes.

If this is the case, then the TOC is being generated by JavaScript in the extension.

Comment: Well that is embarrassing, hey!  :P  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so now I think I have figured it out.  I downloaded a google chrome extension a while ago, and it didn't seem to work - so I forgot about it.  But now thinking about it, I wonder if this is what it does?

[image]

Confirmed, I do not get the `TOC` in FireFox.

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out on your own at the same time I did!